# Convert SAS proc sql to Python(pandas)

Tags: python, sql, count, sas, pandas-groupby

I rewrite some code from SAS to Python using Pandas library.

I've got such code, and I have no idea what should I do with it?

Can you help me, beacase its too complicated for me to do it correct. I've changed the name of columns (for encrypt sensitive data)

This is SAS code:

```
proc sql;
   create table &work_lib..opk_do_inf_4 as 
   select distinct         
            *,
            min(kat_opk) as opk_do_inf,
            count(nr_ks) as ilsc_opk_do_kosztu_infr
from &work_lib..opk_do_inf_3
group by kod_ow, kod_sw, nr_ks, nr_ks_pr, nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9, nazwa_zabiegu
having kat_opk = opk_do_inf
;
quit;
```

This is my try in Pandas:

```
df = self.opk_do_inf_3() -> create DF using other function
df['opk_do_inf'] = df.groupby(by=['kod_ow', 'kod_sw', 'nr_ks', 'nr_ks_pr', 'nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9', 'nazwa_zabiegu'])['kat_opk'].min()
df['ilsc_opk_do_kosztu_infr'] = df.groupby(by=['kod_ow', 'kod_sw', 'nr_ks', 'nr_ks_pr', 'nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9', 'nazwa_zabiegu'])['nr_ks'].count()
df_groupby = df.groupby(by=['kod_ow', 'kod_sw', 'nr_ks', 'nr_ks_pr', 'nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9', 'nazwa_zabiegu']).filter(lambda x: x['kat_opk']==x['opk_do_inf'])
df = df_groupby.reset_index()
df = df.drop_duplcates()
return df
```

Comment: Do want the calculated MIN() and COUNT() values re-merged onto all of the detailed observations the way that SAS will? Or do you just want one observation per BY group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calling `SELECT *` in an aggregate `GROUP BY` query is not valid SQL. SAS may allow it but can yield unknown results. Usually `SELECT` columns should be limited to columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

With that said, aggregate SQL queries can generally be translated in Pandas with [**`groupby.agg()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) operations with `WHERE` (filter before aggregation) or `HAVING` (filter after aggregation) conditions handled using either `.loc` or `query`.

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
       MIN(col1) AS min_col1,
       AVG(col2) AS mean_col2, 
       MAX(col3) AS max_col3, 
       COUNT(*)  AS count_obs

FROM mydata
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING col1 = min(col1)
```

**Pandas**

General

```py
agg_data = (mydata.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"], as_index=False)
                  .agg(min_col1 = ("col1", "min"),
                       mean_col2 = ("col2", "mean"),
                       max_col3 = ("col3", "max"),
                       count_obs = ("col1", "count"))
                  .query("col1 == min_col1")
           )
```

Specific

```
opk_do_inf_4 = (mydata.groupby(["kat_opk", "kod_ow", "kod_sw", "nr_ks", "nr_ks_pr", 
                                "nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9", "nazwa_zabiegu"], 
                                as_index=False)
                      .agg(opk_do_inf = ("kat_opk", "min"),
                           ilsc_opk_do_kosztu_infr = ("nr_ks", "count"))
                      .query("kat_opk == opk_do_inf")
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sqldf function from pandasql package to run the sql query on dataframe. example below

''' from pandasql import sqldf
query = "select top 10 * from df "
newdf = sqldf(query, locals())
'''